# Trying to reload page after clicking similar product

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Im pulling items from a JSON file. I have a class called "showProduct" and once clicked it executes a function and shows the item information on the page. I am trying to call this same function again later in my code on the similar product. I need the page to refresh with that new items contents. Below is my code really hope someone can help me out im not sure what I am doing wrong. I did not include the JSON but i hope just by looking at the class and my code someone will know why it wont work.

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("productsSideBar").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("productsSideBar").style.width = "0";
}

 'use strict';
  
   $.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: '',
    success: function(json){
    
   //check for window hash and display appropriate product category 
    var currentHash = window.location.hash;
    switch(currentHash) 
    {
     case '#tomatoes':
       displayTomatoes(); 
       break;
     default:
          displayAll();
       break;
    }
          
          //display all products function 
    function displayAll() {
     var categoryImage = '';
    
     $.each(json, function (i, item) {
       if (item.itemBrandLetter == "C") {
       categoryImage += '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">' + '<a href="#"' + 'class="showProduct"' + 'data-itempageurl="' + item.itemName + '"' + 'data-itemgmo="' + item.itemGMOFree + '"' + 'data-itembpa="' + item.itemBPAFree + '"' + 'data-itemgluten="' + item.itemGlutenFree + '"' + 'data-itemimage="' + item.imageURL + '"' + 'data-itemname="' + item.itemName + '"' + 'data-itemoz="' + item.itemPackSize + '"' + 'data-itemdescription="' + item.itemDescription + '"' + 'data-itemupc="' + item.itemFullUPC + '">' + '<img class="img-responsive img-hover productImagesCategory" src="' + item.imageURL + '">' + '<h3>' + item.itemName + '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>';
       }
     });
     
     $('#imagesCategoryProducts').hide().html(categoryImage).fadeIn('slow');
     
     //show individual product function on click
     $(".showProduct").click(function(event){
  
       //hide all current products
     $('#productCategories').hide();
 
     //get passed data from other function
     var clickedItemName = '<h1>' + $(this).data('itemname') + '</h1>';
     var clickedItemUPC = $(this).data('itemupc');
     var clickedItemOZ = '<h2>' + $(this).data('itemoz') + '</h2>';
     var clickedItemDescription = '<p>' + $(this).data('itemdescription') + '</p>';
     var clickedItemImage = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded center-block" src="' + $(this).data('itemimage') + '">';
     var clickedItemGluten = $(this).data('itemgluten');
     var clickedItemBPA = $(this).data('itembpa');
     var clickedItemGMO = $(this).data('itemgmo');
     var clickedItemPageURL = $(this).data('itempageurl');
     
     //check if clicked data equals correct item
     $.each(json, function (i, item) {
       if (item.itemName === clickedItemName) {
       clickedItemName 
       }
       if (item.itemFullUPC === clickedItemUPC) {
       clickedItemUPC
       }
       if (item.itemPackSize === clickedItemOZ) {
       clickedItemOZ
       }
       if (item.itemDescription === clickedItemDescription) {
       clickedItemDescription
       }
       if (item.imageURL === clickedItemImage) {
       clickedItemImage
       }
       if (item.itemGlutenFree === clickedItemGluten) {
       clickedItemGluten
       }
       if (item.itemBPAFree === clickedItemBPA) {
       clickedItemBPA
       }
       if (item.itemGMOFree === clickedItemGMO) {
       clickedItemGMO
       }
       
       //assign window hash to each product
       if (item.itemName === clickedItemPageURL) {
       event.preventDefault();
       clickedItemPageURL = clickedItemPageURL.replace(/\s/g, '');
       window.location.hash = clickedItemPageURL; 
       }
     });
     
       //remove extra characters from UPC
       var originalUPC = clickedItemUPC;
       var strippedUPC = '<h2>' + originalUPC.slice(1, -1); + '</h2>'; 
 
       //show individual product information
       $('#productSocialShare').show();
       $('#individualProduct').show();
       $('#relatedProducts').show();   
       
       //append product information to appropriate DIV
       $('#productTitle').html(clickedItemName);
       $('#productUPC').html(strippedUPC);
       $('#productOZ').html(clickedItemOZ);
       $('#productDescription').html(clickedItemDescription);
       $('#productImage').html(clickedItemImage);
       
       //check if gluten free is true and show image
       if (clickedItemGluten == "Y") {
        clickedItemGluten = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded img-margin" src="../images/misc/gluten_free_test.jpg">';
        $('#productGlutenFree').html(clickedItemGluten);
        $('#productGlutenFree').show();
       } else { 
        $('#productGlutenFree').hide();
       }
       
       //check if bpa free is true and show image
       if (clickedItemBPA == "Y") {
        clickedItemBPA = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded img-margin" src="../images/misc/bpa_free_test.jpg">';
        $('#productBPAFree').html(clickedItemBPA);
        $('#productBPAFree').show();
       } else { 
        $('#productBPAFree').hide();
       }
       
       //check if gmo free is true and show image
       if (clickedItemGMO == "Y") {
        clickedItemGMO = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded img-margin" src="../images/misc/gmo_test.jpg">';
        $('#productGMOFree').html(clickedItemGMO);
        $('#productGMOFree').show();
       } else { 
        $('#productGMOFree').hide();
       } 
        
       //show random recipe for each item
       var url = '';
          $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
      var randomRecipe = json[Math.floor(Math.random() * json.length)];
      randomRecipe += '<div>' + '<a href="' + randomRecipe.recipePageURL + '">' + '<img class="img-responsive img-hover similarProductImagesCategory" src="' + randomRecipe.recipeImageCategoryURL + '">' + '</a>' + '<a href="' + randomRecipe.recipePageURL +'">' + '<h3 class="similarProductSubCategoryImgCaption">' + randomRecipe.recipeName + '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>';
          $('#featuredRecipe').append(randomRecipe);     
       });
       
       //show similar products 
       var categoryItems = [];
       $.each(json, function(i, item){
       if(window.location.hash.indexOf('Tomatoes') >= 0) {
        if(item.itemCommodity == '1120' && item.itemBrandLetter == "C") categoryItems.push(item);
       }
       if(window.location.hash.indexOf('Olive') >= 0) {
        if(item.itemCommodity == '2120' && item.itemBrandLetter == "C") categoryItems.push(item);
       }
       });
      
       var similarProduct= '';
       $.each(json, function(i,item){
       similarProduct = categoryItems[Math.floor(Math.random()*categoryItems.length)];
       similarProduct += '<div>' + '<a href="#" class="showProduct"' + '>' + '<img class="img-responsive img-hover similarProductImagesCategory" src="' + similarProduct.imageURL + '">' + '<h3 class="similarProductSubCategoryImgCaption">' + similarProduct.itemName + '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>';
       });
       $('#productSimilar').append(similarProduct); 
     });    
     closeNav();
    }
    
    }
   });
});
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="productsSideBar" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="#" id="displayall"><h3>View All</h3></a>
    <a href="#" id="tomatoes">Tomatoes</a>
    <a href="#" id="sauce">Sauce</a>
    <a href="#" id="oliveoil">Olive Oil</a>
    <a href="#" id="redwinevinegar">Red Wine Vinegar</a>
    <a href="#" id="balsamicvinegar">Balsamic Vinegar</a>
    <a href="#" id="peppers">Peppers</a>
    <a href="#" id="artichokes">Artichokes</a>
    <a href="#" id="olives">Olives</a>
    <a href="#" id="beans">Beans</a>
    <a href="#" id="caperspignolinuts">Capers & Pignoli Nuts</a>
    <a href="#" id="specialties">Specialties</a>
    <a href="#" id="spices">Spices</a>
    <a href="#" id="fish">Fish</a>
    <a href="#" id="brothstockssoups">Broth, Stocks & Soups</a>
    <a href="#" id="breadcrumbs">Breadcrumbs</a>
    <a href="#" id="gratedcheese">Grated Cheese</a>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="productCategories"> 
 <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-12">
              <br>
                <span class="expandSidebar" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Categories</span> 
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-12"> 
              <div id="imagesCategoryProducts"></div> 
             </div>
        </div>
 </div>
</section>

<!-- Product Row Start -->     
<section id="individualProduct"> 
 <div class="container topmargin">
     <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6">
              <!-- Product Title Div -->
              <div id="productTitle"></div>
                <!-- Product UPC Div -->
                <div class="displayInlineBlock" id="productUPC"></div>
                <span class="displayInlineBlock"><h2>•</h2></span>
                <!-- Product OZ Div -->
                <div class="displayInlineBlock" id="productOZ"></div>
                <span class="displayInlineBlock"><h2>•</h2></span>
                <!-- Where to Buy Icon -->
                <div class="displayInlineBlock"><h3><a href="../where-to-buy.php"><span rel="popover" data-content="View Product Availability"><span class="fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span></span></a></h3></div>
                <hr>
                <!-- Product Description Div -->
              <div id="productDescription"></div>
                
                <div class="row center">
                 <!-- Gluten Free Div -->
                 <div class="displayInlineBlock" id="productGlutenFree"></div>
                 <!-- BPA Free Div -->
                 <div class="displayInlineBlock" id="productBPAFree"></div>
                 <!-- GMO Div -->
                 <div class="displayInlineBlock" id="productGMOFree"></div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6">
              <!-- Product Image Div -->
              <div id="productImage"></div>
             </div>
        </div>
 </div>
</section>
<!-- Product Row End -->

<section id="relatedProducts"> 
 <div class="container topmargin">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-7">
                <h1 class="center">Featured Recipe</h1>
             <div id="featuredRecipe"></div>
         </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
             <h1 class="center">Similar Product</h1>
                <br>
                <div id="productSimilar"></div>
         </div>
        </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Try putting your code in a jsfiddle and I will try to help you

Comment: @Chris doing it now thank you so much

Comment: Can I make a suggestion? Rather make something small and basic so you can understand the concept before trying to integrate it into your website. That way you can understand how it works and ask questions if you struggle. Then you can put it in when you can work off an example. The jsfiddle does not work, you literally just copy and pasted the code you posted here, you didn't even include jquery.

Comment: @Chris i did not realize i needed to include the jquery i will attempt to update this for you. but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @Chris i am using this version of jquery i cant get it to integrate http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js

Comment: @Chris can i try sending you a link to what i am working on? not js fiddle so you can it. i cant get it to work in jsfiddle

Comment: @Chris I have included a working example. If you have time I would really appreciate the help. Thanks soo much! http://codepen.io/tcarp/pen/aBPLqX

Comment: I am having a look now

Comment: so you want to let them click on the similar product and it should show the information, am I right? If so then you have 2 mistakes. I am going to make the changes on the codepen. It is 00:40 am here right now so I am going to sleep, but will write you up a proper answer tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I'm looking to do. Thank you again!! I'll check back tomorrow have a great night

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there are a lot of things that are wrong in the code but I am not going to into that right now. To do what you want to achieve is rather simple, you already got all the code you need, you just need to make some adjustments to make it work.

Step one. Bind the click events to the body instead of to the element.

```
$("body").on('click', ".showProduct", function(event){
```

That way, any element on the page with the class showProduct that is clicked will trigger the function, not just the elements that were bound to when the initial function ran.

The rest is really simple, you already have the similar product's information available, you just didn't put it in the data attributes when you created the element. Now obviously there are better ways of doing this... but here is how you would do it:

```
similarProduct = '<div>' + 
    '<a href="#" class="showProduct"' +
    'data-itempageurl="' + similarProduct.itemFullUPC + '"' + 
    'data-itemgmo="' + similarProduct.itemGMOFree + '"' + 
    'data-itembpa="' + similarProduct.itemBPAFree + '"' + 
    'data-itemgluten="' + similarProduct.itemGlutenFree + '"' + 
    'data-itemlowsodium="' + similarProduct.itemLowSodium + '"' + 
    'data-itemorganic="' + similarProduct.itemOrganic + '"' + 
    'data-itemimage="' + similarProduct.imageURL + '"' + 
    'data-itemname="' + similarProduct.itemName + '"' + 
    'data-itemoz="' + similarProduct.itemPackSize + '"' + 
    'data-itemdescription="' + similarProduct.itemDescription + '"' + 
    'data-itemupc="' + similarProduct.itemFullUPC + '"' + '>' + 
    '<img class="img-responsive img-hover similarProductImagesCategory" src="' + similarProduct.imageURL + '">' + 
    '<h3 class="similarProductSubCategoryImgCaption">' + similarProduct.itemName + 
    '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>';
});
```

That should do it... now you will notice when you click on one of the similar products it should show you the information like you wanted, however it will add the new similar product to the already existing similar product list and this will keep on growing the more you click. I am sure you can figure out how to clear the list. If not just shout.

Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYJpve

EDIT: As a side note... normally you want to store the json data with the product id as key. Then you only save the key inside the data attribute. On click you simply use the product id (key) to access the information in your stored object.

It is really easy to do. Just create a global variable

```
var product_data = {};
```

Then you populate the object when you get the data with a function. So on success of your ajax call you could have something like this:

```
product_data = json;
```

or even better you could have a function that changes the data into the structure you want:

```
product_data = restructureDataFunction(json);
```

Then you have a nice data set which you can pull from. If you need to make updates to the dataset you can do it in one place instead of in each element.

If you want, have a look at Angular 2, it should teach you a lot and also help you with future projects. It is really strong tool especially if you have html elements representing data.

Comment: This is great thank you soo much! I really appreciate it. I didnt expect you to have an answer tonight but I really really appreciate the advice!